# Python lists assignment

Tags: python, list, variable-assignment

Python code. I have the following situation: I have a list called data and I assign it to list called no_Relatives_Prots. I then perform some operations on no_Relatives_Prots (not on data!). My assumption would be that only no_Relatives_Prots would be changed. And yet the changes are made to both data and no_Relatives_Prots lists. The code is below.

```
no_Relatives_Prots = data

for i in related:
    redundant_List = i.split(",")
    for g in redundant_List:
        for k,h in enumerate(no_Relatives_Prots):
            if h == 0:
                break
            elif g == h.split("-->")[0]:
                no_Relatives_Prots[k] = 0
```

Comment: And the question is? To copy a list, do `no_Relatives_Prots = data[:]`

Comment: The question is why data list is changed at all? I am still learning Python and did not observe this behavior in Perl